# Cakephp - integrating two applications

Tags: cakephp, integration, subdomain, frontend, authentication

I am build a trade center, and I need two frontend applications for it.
The first is for clients. the second is for stores.

One way is to create two authentication engines and selective routing - if you are a store "go here.." if not - "go there".

The other way is to create two applications:
The main domain will be for the clients and will have auth engine just for them. they will have 0 access to management.
And a sub domain with complete mvc for storos.

insights before i start?

Comment: Why not just make one application and use ACL to separate the controllers you only want clients to access and the ones you want stores to access?

Comment: some of the controllers are shared, like: stores, products and so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it's done in one app with auth and prefix-routings. And I suggest you do this way.

You can use 2 separate apps, as long as all the data you want to share are in one database (that both apps connect to): no shared img folder would be the first obvious disadvantage. There also might be more problems down the road, as this is not a common way to manage user roles.

Comment: I agree, using prefix routing is the way I usually do it, and I work without problems.